# how to get dataframe columns and index on the same level after set_index?

Tags: python, pandas

after setting the index of a dataframe, the columns and index seem to be on different levels

```py
pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[11, 22, 33]}).set_index('A')
```

```
    B
A   
1   11
2   22
3   33
```

`df.index.names` is `FrozenList(['A'])` and `df.columns.names` is `FrozenList([None])` so i couldn't use droplevel for that

The desired output is

```
A   B
1   11
2   22
3   33
```

Comment: That is how index labels are displayed. `df.index.names` produces `FrozenList(['A'])` for me. (assuming `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[11, 22, 33]}).set_index('A')`)

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks for the comment! i corrected the question and tried to make it clearer

Comment: "the columns and index seem to be on different levels" - isn't this what `set_index('A')` does?

Comment: this seems to be the effect of having a value other than `None` for `df.index.name `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in case it might be helpful for someone else.

based on how the dataframe is displayed i thought there was some kind of `MultiIndex` somewhere but as pointed out in the comments, this is just how index labels are displayed so

```py
df.index.name = None
```

removes the extra level effect (that is also visible for example when using `df.to_latex`)

```
    B
1   11
2   22
3   33
```

I was trying `df.index.name = ''` which actually kept the level effect